# Compute a full hand of cards

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I am trying to compute a total value for a hand of cards. If there is no Ace, there will be 1 element in the `final_listarray`. If there is an Ace, there would be 2 elements to represent total possible value of hand of cards (as Ace can be 1 or 11).

For some reason, my array just outputs [0,0], and is not what I want.

(`arraylist1` is just my array holding the values of each card. In this case an Ace would hold both 1 and 11, any other value would hold 1 element)

```
int max_excluding_Ace=0;
int max_adding_1=max_excluding_Ace;
int max_adding_11=max_excluding_Ace;

for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) {
        
    //Add values without aces
    if ((arraylist1.get(i)!=1) && (arraylist1.get(i)!=11)) {
        max_excluding_Ace += arraylist1.get(i);
    }
    //ace               
    //Add values with different combinations of the ace
    else if ((arraylist1.get(i)==1)) {
        max_adding_1 +=1;
    }
    else if ((arraylist1.get(i)==11)) {
        max_adding_11 +=11;
    }
}
if (max_adding_1 != max_excluding_Ace) {
    final_listarray.add(max_adding_1);
    final_listarray.add(max_adding_11);

}
else {
    final_listarray.add(max_excluding_Ace);
}
return final_listarray;
```

Comment: "arraylist1 is just my array holding the values of each card" it would be helpful to know its actual content anyway.

Comment: How are `arraylist1` and `final_listarray` (bad names btw) declared? How do you print your result? Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems to me like a good case to learn using a debugger. Did you try that?

Comment: arraylist1=[8,5,6,1,11] (the first 3 represent EIGHT,FIVE,SIX and the 4th and 5th element is from the ACE card)

Comment: Also, shouldn't you *always* increment `max_adding_1` and `max_adding_11` and only increment `max_excluding_Ace` when the current card is not an ace?

Comment: This method is inside of a class, and i return the final_listarray to get a listarray containing either 1 or 2 elements. It contains 1 if there is no ace, and 2 if there is an ace

Comment: the reason i added max_adding_1 and max_adding_11, is because I need to use them in the final_listarray as max_adding_1 would be the first element, and max_adding_11 is the second element

Comment: @MoR so given `arraylist1=[8,5,6,1,11]` (bad example IHMO) the output should be `[1, 11]`, given, let's say `arraylist1=[8,1,5,6,1,11]` it should be `[2,11]` and given `arraylist1=[8,5,6]` it should be `[19]`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear that `arraylist1` is a list of integers.
Presumably the value of each card in the hand.

When you check `arraylist1.get(i)==1` (or `==11`) this implies that the value of an Ace is already given in the original hand.

But it sounds like what you want is two results: one for if Ace is 1, and one for if Ace is 11.

(Also, if Ace is 11, what is a Jack, Queen, King ?)

I suggest to make the meanings, semantics and intentions clear with a `Card` enum class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public enum Card {
    ACE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3),
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5),
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8),
    NINE(9),
    TEN(10),
    JACK(11),
    QUEEN(11),
    KING(11);

    private final int value;

    private Card(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static int valueOfHand(Iterable<Card> hand, boolean aceIs11) {
        int total = 0;
        for( Card card : hand) {
            if( aceIs11 && card == ACE ) {
                total += 11;
            } else {
                total += card.value;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static Integer[] valuesOfHand(Iterable<Card> hand) {
        int totalAce1 = 0;
        int totalAce11 = 0;
        for( Card card : hand) {
            if( card == ACE ) {
                totalAce1 += 1;
                totalAce11 += 11;
            } else {
                totalAce1 += card.value;
                totalAce11 += card.value;
            }
        }
        return new Integer[] {totalAce1, totalAce11};
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Card> hand = Arrays.asList( TWO, ACE, KING, ACE );
        System.out.println( valueOfHand( hand, false)); // 15
        System.out.println( valueOfHand( hand, true)); // 35
        System.out.println( Arrays.asList(valuesOfHand( hand ))); // 15, 35
    }
}
```